Remove Nan in pointcloud when loading via Open3D
I'm trying to open a pcd file in python using open3d,
but the array of the point cloud is filled by nan.
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
from pypcd4 import PointCloud

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("TestData1/000_00_cloud.pcd")
    print(pcd)
    print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

Error:
Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it
PointCloud with 518400 points.
[[nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]
 ...
 [nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]]

How can i exclude the nan point?
I need to do something with the numpy?

There are 2 ways to do this -

Pass remove_nan_points=True and remove_infinite_points=True to o3d.io.read_point_cloud.
Read the pointcloud and later call pcd.remove_non_finite_points()

See docs here and here.
